# get value of webservice async function

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

I have a simple asp.net webservice which has a simple async function like so:

```
public class TestService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public async Task<string> HelloWorld()
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

and I want to get the result of it in my asp.net webforms app like so:

```
 public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(GetFullName));
        }

        async Task<string> GetFullName()
        {
            var client = new TestService.TestServiceSoapClient();
            return await client.HelloWorldAsync();
        }
    }
```

but I get the error:

```
CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'digital_sig_webapp.TestService.HelloWorldResponse' to 'string'
```

I am expecting a result type of string here, so what is happening?
how can I get the value out of it?

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is one of the HelloWorldResponse's fileds. The name should be HelloWorldResult. So your code can be something like this(Not tested):

```
    async Task<string> GetFullName()
    {
        var client = new TestService.TestServiceSoapClient();
        var response = await client.HelloWorldAsync();
        return response.HelloWorldResult;
    }
```

Comment: we would still get  `Cannot implicitly convert type 'digital_sig_webapp.TestService.TaskOfString' to 'string'`